# Unable to Override Admin .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

I am developing custom plugin, in which i'm adding note in customer information data from Manage customer.
I also want to show that note in order with customer information. I need to override one file

```
design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

My config file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Module>
      <version>1.0.0.1</version>
    </Company_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <module>
        <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
      </module>
      <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
         <customer_grid>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
        </rewrite>
        <rewrite>
        <sales_order_view_info>Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
        </rewrite>
     </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <module>
        <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </module>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <module_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Company_Module</module>
          <class>Company_Module_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
      </module_setup>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <module>
          <file>module.xml</file>
        </module>
      </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        <observers>
          <module>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>saveCustomerTabData</method>
          </module>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
    </events>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And Block file is `app/local/Company/Module/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
{
    public function __construct()
    {


        $this->setTemplate('module/sales/order/view/info.phtml');
        echo $this->getTemplate(); //correct path showing 


    }

    public function getCommentCustomer($orderID)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($orderID);
        return $customer->getComment(); // comment i have added from tab
    }
}
```

I am using template hint extension.  Its showing correct Correct Block but showing wrong  .phtml path.  Instead of `module/sales/order/view/info.phtml` it shows `/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow two tutorial, this will be help you.

[How to overwrite sales view order phtml file in magento](https://sohel.dev/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento/)

[How to add custom block after items block into order view page in magento](https://sohel.dev/how-to-add-custom-block-after-items-block-into-order-view-page-in-magento/)

Comment: It worked , but i don't know why my code didn't worked. 
I changed only module.xml and Info.php file

Comment: Links are no more working

Comment: Modified the link @AkshayPrabhakar